# Setting Parent in user component

Tags: c++builder-xe5

I've created two user components in XE5. The first is a descendant of TCustomPanel and its purpose is to be a container for the second component, that its a descendant of TCustomLabel.

The container.

```
class PACKAGE TMenuPanel : public TCustomPanel
{
private:
protected:
public:
    __fastcall TMenuPanel(TComponent* Owner);
__published:
    __property Align;
    __property Caption;
};

static inline void ValidCtrCheck(TMenuPanel *)
{
    new TMenuPanel(NULL);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TMenuPanel::TMenuPanel(TComponent* Owner)
    : TCustomPanel(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace Menupanel
{
    void __fastcall PACKAGE Register()
    {
        TComponentClass classes[1] = {__classid(TMenuPanel)};
        RegisterComponents(L"Isis", classes, 0);
    }
}
```

The contained.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class PACKAGE TMenuLabel : public TCustomLabel
{
private:
    UnicodeString   FOption;
    int             FIndex;
    bool            FHighlighted;
protected:
    UnicodeString   __fastcall GetOption();
    void            __fastcall SetOption(UnicodeString Option);
    int             __fastcall GetIndex();
    void            __fastcall SetIndex(int Index);
    void            __fastcall SetHighlighted(bool Flag);
    void            __fastcall RecaptionLabel();
public:
    __fastcall TMenuLabel(TComponent* Owner);
__published:

  __property int            Index = {read=GetIndex, write=SetIndex, nodefault};
  __property UnicodeString  Option = {read=GetOption, write=SetOption, nodefault};
  __property bool           Highlighted = {read=FHighlighted, write=SetHighlighted, nodefault};
};

static inline void ValidCtrCheck(TMenuLabel *)
{
    new TMenuLabel(NULL);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TMenuLabel::TMenuLabel(TComponent* Owner)
    : TCustomLabel(Owner)
{
    if (!Name.IsEmpty()) {
        FOption = L"Option"+Name;
    } else {
        FOption = L"Option";
    }
    FHighlighted = false;
}
```

So far so good, components are installed, they appear in the palette and their properties in the inspector. But...

If the MenuPanel is placed on the form MenuLabels are placed in it. If it's placed on a Panel in the Form the menu labels are placed in the Panel. Funny though if the MenuPanel placed in the form is cut and pasted on the panel the MenuLabels are in the MenuPanel.

[image: MenuLabels in MenuPanels]

I know this has to do with setting the parent property for MenuPanel, but the constructor takes an TComponent *Owner parameter which is the Form. Yet Panels can be placed within Panels, within Panels and a Label will be placed in the right one.

Has anybody come across the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you drop a component in the Form Designer, its `Parent` becomes the currently focused component (if its `ControlStyle` contains `csAcceptsControls`, otherwise its `Parent` is used instead, and so on until `csAcceptsControls` is found). So make sure your MenuPanel component has the `csAcceptsControls` flag enabled in its constructor, and that your MenuPanel is selected in the Form Designer when dropping the MenuLabel objects.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I've come across with another solution to resolve a handle to the Parent both a design and run time. Overriding CreateParams, calling the base class and retrieving WndParent from it.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a reference to the component parent as it has values for specific child components font colors. ParentFont provides FontName, Size, Styles, but the container defines font color attributes for specific TStaticText derived components.

The container defines:

```
MESSAGE void __fastcall MPIntHandler(TMyIntMessage &Msg);
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(IC_GETCOLOR, TMyIntMessage, MPIntHandler);
END_MESSAGE_MAP(TComponent)


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TMenuPanel::MPIntHandler(TMyIntMessage &Msg)
{
    WPARAM WP = *Msg.wparam;
    WORD lWord = LOWORD(WP);
    if (lWord == CLR_LABEL) {
        OutputDebugStringA("Returning FLabelColor");
        Msg.Result = (long)FLabelColor;
    } else {
        OutputDebugStringA("lWord != CLR_LABEL");
        Msg.Result = (long)clRed;
    }
}
```

The child overrides CreateParams:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    void __fastcall TMenuLabel::CreateParams(TCreateParams &Params)
    {
    int wParam = MAKEWPARAM(CLR_LABEL,0);
    int lParam = 0;

        OutputDebugStringA("CreateParams");
        TStaticText::CreateParams(Params);
        if (Params.WndParent != NULL) {
            hwndParent = Params.WndParent;
            LRESULT lRes = SendGetIntMessage(hwndParent,IC_GETCOLOR,wParam,lParam);
            Font->Color = (TColor)lRes;
        }
    }
```

This works both at design and run time.